# How do I save excel file with multiple sheets from pyspark data frame

Tags: excel, pyspark

I'm  new to pyspark & working in pyspark 3.0.1 on data bricks. I have two pyspark data frame,df1 & df2, which I need to save in two sheet of an excel file in ADLS gen2. So I wrote the following script

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path+"multipleSheet.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
df1.toPandas().to_excel(writer, sheet_name='df1')
df2.toPandas().to_excel(writer, sheet_name='df2')
writer.save()
```

where path is my ADLS path. Unfortunately I'm not finding error while running the code & also not seeing the excel file in my ADLS

Am I doing anything wrong? Kindly suggest

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save multiple sheets in one file you can use:

```
import pandas as pd

with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    df1.toPandas().to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_1')
    df2.toPandas().to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_2')
```

You can also try the default write engine `openpyxl` (need to be installed) instead of  `xlsxwriter`.

Comment: it's also doing the same thing. Neither I'm getting error nor it's saving in ADLS. It's looking like me that there is some problem of saving file in ADLS. My original code was saving excel in local but not in ADLS

Comment: Is there any solution for ADLS gen2 please?

Comment: Make another question about ADLS gen2.